# Matrix getBlockTypesByFieldId() function doesn't work as intended?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

One of the functions in a plugin that I'm working on, is the ability to create fields. It has created a Matrix field, and directly after that, I want to know the MatrixBlockType.

I don't get any results if I use the following code:

```php
$blockTypes = craft()>matrix>getBlockTypesByFieldId($newField->id, 'handle');
```

However, if I do the exact same thing as the above function should do, and run this code I do have results:

```php
$results = craft()->db->createCommand()
->select('id, fieldId, fieldLayoutId, name, handle, sortOrder')
->from('matrixblocktypes')
->where('fieldId = :fieldId', array(':fieldId' => $newField>id))
->order('sortOrder')
->queryAll();
```

If you would debug both variables, you'll notice that the first one doesn't contain any data.

If I would be creating the fields and in later server request I would use the first example, I do receive the data. Somehow it's not available right after creating the field.

Can anyone help me out here by any chance? I want to use the first example, which is the correct way.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Try sending a mail to support@buildwithcraft.com and update this question if you can solve your problem. :)

Comment: Why aren't there any dashes/hyphens before the greater-than signs in your first code example?

Comment: @Hubert Have you made any progress with this? Curious whether it ended up being a bug.

Comment: @Willingham I posted this on Google plus first. Apparently it removes the dashes.

Comment: @Matt No progress yet. Picked it up with Brad, so i'll update this when I know more.

Comment: @Hubert Replied to your ticket on the 9th and haven't heard back, just in case you didn't receive it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this *was* a bug in Craft and we've just fixed it for the next (post build 2568) release.